# Integral of $f(x)$ of region between $y=0$ and $y=4-x^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, positive-definite

The limits of the integral
$$\iint 2xy\,dy\,dx$$
in the region between
$$\left(4-x^2\right)$$ and $$y=0$$ are 
$$-2\leq x\leq2$$
and 
$$0\leq y\leq4-x^2$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by the limits of the integral?

Comment: If you meant the region enclosed by curves $y=4-x^2$ and $y=0$, then yes: it is indeed the set $$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, -2\le x\le 2\wedge 0\le y\le 4-x^2\}$$

Comment: I might call it "the region between $y=4-x^2$ and $y=0$.  The presence of $\text{“}y=\cdots\text{''}$ is essential. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed.   Because $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ are the two intercepts of the curves, then $\{(x,y): x\in[-2;2], y\in[0;4-x^2]\}$ is the region enclosed by those curves.   Thus the definite integral you seek is:

$$\int_{-2}^2\int_0^{4-x^2} 2xy \operatorname d y\operatorname d x$$

Continue from here.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!